# Did I accidentally lock myself out of my PC forever?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for an exercise. I had to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to set a max 3 attempted logins for users. However instead of putting the commands in the start like I was supposed to,

I put them in the end, saved and exited. Afterwards I couldn't use the password for any user, it says wrong password even though I enter the correct one.

Is this fixable somehow without needing to reinstall?

Below a screenshot of the common-auth file after I messed with it.

[image: common-auth file]

Comment: You can probably fire up any Linux LiveUSB, mount your install within it and then edit the file back as required.

Comment: don't post screenshot of texts. Copy the text and paste here in proper formatting

Answer (score 2):

That last line doesn't make sense at the end *nor* at the start – there's no 'audit' module type in PAM, and there is no 'even_deny_root' action. Rather, all of those should have been parameters added to the *existing* `pam_tally2.so` line. If you're using nano, make sure to disable its line wrapping using `nano --nowrap [...]`.

> Is this fixable somehow without needing to reinstall?

Reboot the system into "rescue mode" (or into any Linux liveCD/liveUSB), log in as root (in Ubuntu this probably will let you in without a password), edit the file, reboot again.

If the bootloader doesn't have a "rescue mode" option, press <kbd>e</kbd> in the menu and add the option `rescue` to the 'linux' line. If that doesn't work, add the option `emergency` instead. If *that* doesn't work, add the option `init=/bin/sh`. (These are the same instructions as found in various "how to reset root password" tutorials.)

When the system boots with either 'emergency' or 'init=/bin/sh' options, the root filesystem will be read-only at first; use `mount -o remount,rw /` to fix that (before trying to edit anything). The full rescue mode shouldn't need this. After editing, run `sync` (to flush filesystem changes – just in case) and reboot.